# How to check if a cloud firestore document exists when using realtime updates

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

This works:

```
db.collection('users').doc('id').get()
  .then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      db.collection('users').doc('id')
        .onSnapshot((doc) => {
          // do stuff with the data
        });
    }
  });
```

... but it seems verbose. I tried `doc.exists`, but that didn't work. I just want to check if the document exists, before subscribing to realtime updates on it. That initial get seems like a wasted call to the db.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish an instert/update or?

Comment: its now `db.collection('users').doc('id').ref.get()`

Answer (score 209):

Your initial approach is right, but it may be less verbose to assign the document reference to a variable like so:

```
const usersRef = db.collection('users').doc('id')

usersRef.get()
  .then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      usersRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        // do stuff with the data
      });
    } else {
      usersRef.set({...}) // create the document
    }
});
```

Reference: [Get a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: It appears that the code has undergone a change in structure, transitioning from evaluating a boolean property to invoking a function
Previously:
```if (docSnapshot.exists)```
It should now be:
```if (docSnapshot.exists())```

Answer (score 19):

Please check following code. It may help you.

```
 const userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_name').doc('doc_id');
   const doc = await userDocRef.get();
   if (!doc.exists) {
     console.log('No such document exista!');
   } else {
     console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know its late, but it's actually snapshot.empty not snapshot.exists .
snapshot.empty checks if a doc exists and returns accordingly. happy coding

Comment: Both `exists` and `empty` are valid depending on the snapshot type.
Query snapshots - such that return a list of snapshots have `querySnapshot.empty` as in "a list is empty". Document snapshot is for a single document and they have `documentSnapshot.exists` field as in "a document exists"

Answer (score 3):

Please note that in Firebase v9 (Modular SDK) `exists` is a method, not a property (which would give you `falsy` results all the time), as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_3).

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with a returned `false` value. The documentation explains that if there is no document, it'll return false. The goal would therefore be to make code that is idempotent and would work with the guiding principles of firestore

The documentation explains: 
`Note: If there is no document at the location referenced by docRef, the resulting document will be empty and calling exists on it will return false.`

I recommend using the methods that the devs have created

Comment: @New-Way not really sure what you’re trying to say, to be honest. I simply mentioned in v9 exists is a method, not a property anymore, so be aware.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using PHP-Firestore integration, like me, write something like this:

```
$firestore = new FirestoreClient();
$document = $firestore->document('users/john');
$snapshot = $document->snapshot();

if ($snapshot->exists()) {
   echo "John is there!";
}
```

Enjoy! o/