# What's the best way to check if a Firestore record exists if its path is known?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Given a given Firestore path what's the easiest and most elegant way to check if that record exists or not short of creating a document observable and subscribing to it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880323/how-to-check-if-a-cloud-firestore-document-exists-when-using-realtime-updates) it looks like `.exists` can still be used just like with the standard Firebase database. Additionally, you can find some more people talking about this issue on github [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1272)

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) states

**NEW EXAMPLE**

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

**OLD EXAMPLE**

```
const cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
const doc = await cityRef.get();
    
if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
} else {
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}
```

> Note: If there is no document at the location referenced by docRef, the resulting document will be empty and calling exists on it will return false.

**OLD EXAMPLE 2**

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

var getDoc = cityRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log('No such document!');
        } else {
            console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I think your answer has some omissions though?

Comment: What do you mean? Is there a use case I'm missing or something?

Comment: I meant the code doesn't add up the way you wrote it. Maybe some things got lost when you were pasting it.

Comment: Yeah that would be because I looked at the Swift code since I do iOS. I updated my answer to have JavaScript so it matches your question.

Comment: Is the get function deprecated?

Comment: the `Get()` function is still used in Google Documentation as of 9-9-19 so I don't think it's deprecated.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. When I use it, the get function returns an observable and not a promise. You need to add docRef.ref.get

Comment: Thank you a lot for answer, it is very helpful. Do you maybe know how to check if value in document exists?

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth In what version of firebase are you getting an observable from `get`? I would love that. Half my code is converting snapshots to observables...  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get

Answer (score 10):

If the model contains too many fields, a better approach would be to apply a field mask on the `CollectionReference::get()` result (let's save more google cloud traffic plan, \o/).
Use the  `CollectionReference::select()` + `CollectionReference::where()` to select only what we want to read from the firestore.

Let's assume we have the same collection schema as firestore [cities example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#example_data), but with an `id` field in our doc with the same value of the `doc::id`. Then you can do:

```js
var docRef = db.collection("cities").select("id").where("id", "==", "SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (!doc.empty) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc[0].data());
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Now we download just the `city::id` instead of download entire doc just to check if it exists.

Comment: Does that really work? I am trying to find the `select()` method under [Collection Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) and I couldn't find it.

Comment: @cbdeveloper, [Collection Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) inherits [Query<T>](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) which one have the ```select()``` method. But the documentation doesn't show it :(. You can find it on the source code [reference.ts](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/master/dev/src/reference.ts).

Answer (score 6):

Check this :)

```
  var doc = firestore.collection('some_collection').doc('some_doc');
  doc.get().then((docData) => {
    if (docData.exists) {
      // document exists (online/offline)
    } else {
      // document does not exist (only on online)
    }
  }).catch((fail) => {
    // Either
    // 1. failed to read due to some reason such as permission denied ( online )
    // 2. failed because document does not exists on local storage ( offline )
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

**2022 answer**: You can now use the [`count()` aggregation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) to check if a document exists *without downloading it*.
Here is a TypeScript example:

```js
import { getCountFromServer, query, collection, documentId } from '@firebase/firestore'

const db = // ...

async function userExists(id: string): Promise<boolean> {
  const snap = await getCountFromServer(query(
    collection(db, 'users'), where(documentId(), '==', id)
  ))
  return !!snap.data().count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Encountered Same Problem recently while using Firebase Firestore and i used following approach to overcome it.

```
mDb.collection("Users").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("tasks").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (task.getResult().isEmpty()){
                    Log.d("Test","Empty Data");
                }else{
                 //Documents Found . add your Business logic here
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

task.getResult().isEmpty() provides solution that if documents against our query was found or not

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which library you are using, it may be an observable instead of a promise.  Only a promise will have the 'then' statement. You can use the 'doc' method instead of the collection.doc method, or toPromise() etc.  Here is an example with the doc method:

```
let userRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`)
.get()
.then((doc) => {
  if (!doc.exists) {

  } else {

  }
});

})
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you wanted to use an observable and rxjs in angular instead of a promise:

```js
this.afs.doc('cities', "SF")
.valueChanges()
.pipe(
  take(1),
  tap((doc: any) => {
  if (doc) {
    console.log("exists");
    return;
  }
  console.log("nope")
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be out of date, but wanted to add my thoughts... There is a "limit" function now which restricts the query, and for "exists" we only really need 0 or 1.

So I think the most efficient "exists" would be to add the limit against the query, and then "count" - a helper function like;

```
  private async exists(query: firestore.Query<firestore.DocumentData, firestore.DocumentData>): Promise<boolean> {
    const constrainedCount = await query.limit(1).count().get();
    return constrainedCount.data().count > 0;
  }
```