# Is there any way to find if something exist inside the list in firebase database?

Tags: json, firebase, dictionary, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore in flutter. I have to create a group like whatsapp group for that I'm getting group name, group currency,group admin and a list of members which includes fullname and phonenumber as you can see

```
groupadmin : "+923009399237"
groupcurrency : "USD"
groupmembers : "[
            {"fullname":"ABC",
             "phonenumber":"+923475894561"
            },
            {"fullname":"ASD",
             "phonenumber":"+922222222211"
            }
            ]"
groupname : "First Group"
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
 Firestore.instance
    .collection('groups')
    .where("groupmember.phonenumber", isEqualTo: 090909090)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) {
  if (data.documents.length > 0) {
 }
```

Is there anyway to directly find the group which has member with phonenumber == 0909090909. Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that you can also add `exists` to your Firestore rules as well. This way you can call a Firebase Function that relies on data existing, and then safely handle success/errors by placing things within a try/catch. Note that `exists` counts as a Firestore read (for billing purposes).

e.g. 
`allow create: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))`

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Use property `exists`:

```
 Firestore.instance
    .collection('groups')
    .where("groupmember.phonenumber", isEqualTo: 090909090)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) {
  if (data.exists) console.log("Yeah !");
 }
```

See also: [What's the best way to check if a Firestore record exists if its path is known?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308159/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-firestore-record-exists-if-its-path-is-known)

And please read the doc before posting https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Comment: Can you please refer to some flutter example?

Comment: Maybe this topic might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122211/check-if-field-already-exists-in-flutter-firestore