# How to check unique alias in cloud firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i want to check nick name in hashmap but i didn't get all document from cloud firebase? How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val docRef = db.collection("User").document()
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents->
    
    if (documents != null) {

        val obj= documents.get("Basic Information") as HashMap<*, *>
        val checkNick= obj["nick"].toString()

        if (checkNick == nick){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code creates a reference to a new, non-existing document:

```
val docRef = db.collection("User").document()
```

Since the document doesn't exist yet, calling `docRef.get()` leads to an empty snapshot.

---

If you want to load a specific document, you'll need to know its document ID and specify that in the call to `document`:

```
val docRef = db.collection("User").document("documentIdThatYouWantToLoad")
```

---

If you want to check whether any document exists in the collection for the given nickname, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries):

```
val query = db.collection("User").whereEqualTo("nick", nick)
```

Since a query can [get multiple documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), you also need to handle that differently:

```
query.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
    if (!documents.empty) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    for (document in documents) {
        Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
    }
}
.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
}
```

Also see:

- [Firestore query - checking if username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570270/firestore-query-checking-if-username-already-exists)
- [What's the best way to check if a Firestore record exists if its path is known?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61263457/209103)
- [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032126/209103)
- [I want to make unique usernames in firebase/firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111638/i-want-to-make-unique-usernames-in-firebase-firestore)