# Is possible to check if a collection or sub collection exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to check if a sub collection exists in firestore for nodejs?

Currently I am using `doc.exists` for documents but I need to check if a subcolletion exists within a document in order to write some data or not.

Comment: Another answer I found that works great for this is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880323/how-to-check-if-a-cloud-firestore-document-exists-when-using-realtime-updates. This also works on subcollections as described here https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/559

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use docs.length to know if the subcollection exists.

I made a sample to guide you, hope it helps.

```
 this.db.collection('users').doc('uid')
  .get().limit(1).then(
  doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      this.db.collection('users').doc('uid').collection('friendsSubcollection').get().
        then(sub => {
          if (sub.docs.length > 0) {
            console.log('subcollection exists');
          }
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: That's great, however wouldn't this actually make N number of reads. If that's the case, it might be better to limit the number of returned docs => *.limit(1).

Comment: What if the collection doesn't contain any docs? and is still existent?

Comment: @AkashGorai no. There is no empty collection.

Answer (score 41):

Mateus' Answer didn't help me. Probably it has been changed over the time.

`.collection(..).get()` returns a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) which has the property `size`, so I just did:

```js
admin.firestore
     .collection('users')
     .doc('uid')
     .collection('sub-collection')
     .limit(1)
     .get()
     .then(query => query.size);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use .limit(1)?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot No it is not, but this limits the query size if you don't need to fetch all the docs later on - probably good for pagination.
So you could use it like this:

const snapshot = await admin.firestore.collection(`users/${uid}/sub-collection`).get()

const doesDocsExist = snapshot.size ? true : false

Comment: It is. It'll be faster and it will count less against your quota

Answer (score 6):

To be more precise:

```
const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('uid').collection('sub-collection').limit(1).get()
if (querySnapshot.empty) {console.log('sub-collection not existed')}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I was able to check if a collection exists?

**I target the document path first, then if it exists, It means the collection afterwards exists and I can access it.**

> ```
> >  db.collection("collection_name").document("doc_name").get()
> >        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
> >                     @Override
> >                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
> >                         if(task.isSuccessful()){
> >                             DocumentSnapshot result = task.getResult();
> >                             if(result.exists()){
> >                                *//this means the document exist first, hence the 
> >                                 //collection afterwards the doc_name will 
> >                                 //exist...now I can access the collection*  
> > db.collection("collection_name").document("doc_name").collection("collection_name2").get()
> > .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {    if(task1.isSuccessful()){
> >       ...
> >     } }); } } });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

[`isEmpty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) property of `QuerySnapshot` returns `true` if there are no documents in the QuerySnapshot.

Thus you can simply check if `isEmpty` is `true` or `false`.

```js
const subcolRef = collection(db, "parentCollectionTitle", "parentDocId", "subcollectionTitle")
const subcolSnapshot = await getDocs(subcollectionRef)

if (!subcolSnapshot.empty) {
    console.log("subcol does exists!");
} else {
    console.log("subcol does NOT exist!");
}
```

(Firebase v9)

Answer (score 0):

This is NextJS (React) code for checking if a sub-collection "history" exists or not in collection "users" > doc>user-Id,
if it exists then take data in history, else keep have-history == false.
you can then use `{havehistory?<></>:<></>}` for showing different info, as per data.

```
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([])
const [havehistory, setHavehistory] = useState(false)

if(user){
  onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "users", user.uid,"history")), (querySnapshot) => {
    if(querySnapshot){
      const historyBro = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
      });
      setHistory(historyBro)
      setHavehistory(true)
    }
  })
}
```

make sure your imported the required modules. e.g.

`import { useState } from "react";`

`import {db} from '../firebase'`

`import { collection,doc, query, onSnapshot} from "firebase/firestore";`

`import Link from "next/link";`