# Query for documents containing subcollection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

Is there a way to query for all documents containing a specific subcollection (or alternatively any subcollection at all) in a single query?

This answer: [Is possible to check if a collection or sub collection exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997748/is-possible-to-check-if-a-collection-or-sub-collection-exists) suggests using the document length. Is it possible to do this check within a single query?

Ideally something like this would be possible:

```
db.collection("stuff")
            .whereEqualTo("fu", true)
            .containing("subcollection");
```

Context: I am using a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter to populate a RecyclerView with this query. That's why I can't to the filtering locally. I am aware that introducing an indicator field in the document would solve the problem, but would ideally like to avoid this.

Comment: Firestore doesn't support queries across collections.  A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.  Subcollections are are their own collections - they really have no relation to the higher level collection except by organization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a query is possible.

The best I can think of is keeping a field in the parent document that flags when you add something to the subcollection.

```
db.collection("stuff")
  .whereEqualTo("fu", true)
  .whereEqualTo("somethingAddedToSubcollection", true);
```

Admittedly not ideal, since every write to the subcollection would now require a second write to the document itself, so I hope someone else knows a better solution.