# Not getting all the documents in a collection Firebase Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get all the documents in a collection and `.forEach` document do a query of a sub collection and get the latest (by date) document out of it, but for some reason the query size always is 0

Here is the code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

/// Updates the last payment done in the neighbors documents
export const updateLastPaymentHTTP = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    try {
      const neighbors = await admin.firestore()
                                   .collection("neighbors").get();
      const promises = [];
      neighbors.forEach(async (neighbor) => {
        const topPaymentRef = admin.firestore()
                                   .collection(`neighbors/${neighbor.ref}/payments`)
                                   .orderBy("date", "desc")
                                   .limit(1)
                                   .get();
        const querySize = await topPaymentRef.then((query) => query.size);
        console.log(`Query Size: ${querySize}`);
        if (querySize === 1) {
          const lastPayment = (await topPaymentRef).docs[0].data();
          promises.push(neighbor.ref.update({ last_payment: lastPayment }));
        } else {
          promises.push(neighbor.ref.update({ last_payment: "" }));
        }
      });
      await Promise.all(promises);
      response.send("Update Last Payments Completed");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error Updating Last Payment ${error}`);
    }
  }
);
```

I do the query check because in some neighbor documents there is not a sub collection called payments but in most of them there is:

[With Payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMY17.png)

and

[Without Payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxhvx.png)

But my `querySize === 1` is always false and i update `{ last_payment: '' }`. I have also tried every option explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997748/is-possible-to-check-if-a-collection-or-sub-collection-exists), Is there something wrong with my collection query?

Comment: Are you sure that `neighbor.ref` contains the value you expect?

Comment: Hi Doug it seems that is the problem, any tips in how I can test the `neighbor.ref`? printing all of them into the logs?, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have to do something to debug this.  Logging is one way.

Comment: I managed to log each id with `neighbor.ref.id` and I can confirm that the references of each neighbor are right

Comment: OK, so maybe you want to use `neighbor.ref.id` instead of `neighbor.ref` in your document path?

Comment: Yes that did it, I will update the answer now, again thanks a lot Doug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up Renaud code and Doug solution I found that the problem was related to the `neighbor.ref` I changed to `neighbor.ref.id` then everything worked, Here is my changes in Renaud's code:

First I added a constant so save each of the neighbors ids and add them to a list:

```
  neighbors.forEach((neighbor) => {
    const neighborId = neighbor.ref.id;  /// Here
    promises.push(
      db
        .collection(`neighbors/${neighborId}/payments`)
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .limit(1)
        .get()
    );

    neighborsRefsId.push(neighborId);  /// And Here
  });
```

Then after getting the promises for all neighbors I created a variable named `refDoc` to save all the references for each query with the `idx` and updated the documents accordingly.

```
   const paymentsQuerySnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promises);

      promises = [];
      paymentsQuerySnapshotsArray.forEach((paymentsQuerySnapshot, idx) => {
        const refDoc = db.doc(`/neighbors/${neighborsRefsId[idx]}`);
        if (paymentsQuerySnapshot.size === 1) {
          const lastPayment = paymentsQuerySnapshot.docs[0].data();
          promises.push(refDoc.update({ last_payment: lastPayment }));
        } else {
          promises.push(refDoc.update({ last_payment: "" }));
        }
      });
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

There are several places in your code that need to be adapted:

- You mix-up `async/await` with `then()`
- You use `async/await` in a `forEach` loop (not really recommended, see https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

The following should work (untested):

```
export const updateLastPaymentHTTP = functions.https.onRequest(
    async (request, response) => {
        try {

            const db = admin.firestore();

            const neighbors = await db.collection("neighbors").get();

            const neighborsRefs = [];
            let promises = [];

            neighbors.forEach((neighbor) => {

                promises.push(db.collection(`neighbors/${neighbor.ref}/payments`)
                    .orderBy("date", "desc")
                    .limit(1)
                    .get());

                neighborsRefs.push(neighbor.ref);

            });

            const paymentsQuerySnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promises);

            promises = [];
            paymentsQuerySnapshotsArray.forEach((paymentsQuerySnapshot, idx) => {

                if (paymentsQuerySnapshot.size === 1) {
                    const lastPayment = paymentsQuerySnapshot.docs[0].data();
                    promises.push(neighborsRefs[idx].update({ last_payment: lastPayment }));
                } else {
                    promises.push(neighborsRefs[idx].update({ last_payment: "" }));
                }

            })

            await Promise.all(promises);
            response.status(200).send("Update Last Payments Completed");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error Updating Last Payment ${error}`);
            response.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Renaud unfortunately the function behaves exactly like the one originally posted, it updates all the neighbors to `last_payment: ''"` still I learned a lot with your code, any other ideas why this may be happening, it may be something related with the `neighbor.ref`?